# Django filter queryset by timedelta

Tags: python, django

What could be nice way to filter devices which response was later than, for example, 500 seconds?

So assume my model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    last_response = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My best move was:

```
from django.utils import timezone

for d in Device.objects.all():
    now = timezone.now()
    if d.last_response and (now - d.last_response).seconds < 500:
        # Do something
```

But I don't want to query all database for this. How can I make it work with filter, like `for d in Device.objects.filter(..some arguments..):` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
Device.objects.filter(last_response__lte=timezone.now()-timedelta(seconds=500))
```